# Ensure value labels are displayed

Tags: amcharts

I want to keep value labels outside my `amChart` graph. The problem is that when value label value is over `9999` then I cant display it's all content.

[image]

In this example values should be:

- 25,000
- 20,000
- 15,000
- 10,000
- 5,000

First digit is missing. I am dealing with this only by setting panel's margin

```
"panelsSettings": {
                "marginLeft": 40,
                "marginRight": 20,
            },
```

Is there any more convienient way to be sure that labels are fitting? hardcoding margin seems to be overkill.

This is my example chart: https://jsfiddle.net/29w35txy/1/

Comment: Can you please share the complete config of your chart, or create a code pen?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp Sure, here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/29w35txy/1/

Comment: Where does this chart reproduce your issue? The left axis looks quite normal.

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp It's not for me: https://puu.sh/D52Ao/75d06241da.png

Comment: It seems that your issue is Browser depending. I tested it in Firefox now and got the result you showed. In Chrome it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments above, it seems that this issue is depending on the default Browser font.

So it is working in Chrome (left), but does not work in Firefox (right) for me:

[image] [image]

Beside that you can prevent this by increasing `marginLeft` of your `panelsSettings` which you are already using:

```
"panelsSettings": {
    "marginLeft": 60,
    // ...
},
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/er36bkhq/) I forked you fiddle to show the result.